# Exclude directories from searching entire system

Tags: linux, find, rhel

I need to search for all files that have certain permissions while excluding two directories under `/`. These directories contain far to much information and the system chokes on them.

I've tried various combinations of `-type` `-path` `-wholename` and `-prune` and cannot seem to get it to exclude these two directories.

Currently this is what I am attempting.

```
find . -path './dir1/' -prune -o -path './dir2/' -prune -o -type d -perm -002 ! -perm -1000 > wwlist
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This question belongs on https://superuser.com/ or https://unix.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Meant to add a comment as well as just closing this. But in particular, your syntax would be something like `find \( -path './dir1' -o -path './dir2' \) -type d -prune -o -type -d -perm -002 ! -perm -1000 -print > wwlist`. Which would get treated logically as `find ((-path './dir1' -o -path './dir2)) AND -type d AND -prune) OR (-type -d AND -perm -002 AND (! -perm -1000) AND -print)` . Also not positive, but I believe that find won't treat `-path './dir1'` and `-path './dir1/'` the same, and I think the first will match the path at that point.

Answer (score 0):

You can add conditions that would exclude directories:

```
find . '!' -path './dir1/*' '!' -path './dir2/*' ...
```

To be more precise also exclude the directory themselves:

```
find . '!' -path './dir1' '!' -path './dir2' '!' -path './dir1/*' '!' -path './dir2/*' ...
```

You can also use regex:

```
find . -regextype posix-extended -not -regex '[.]/dir(1|2)(/.*)?' ...
```

- You can also use `-not` instead of `!` but it's not POSIX compliant.
- `-wholename` is synonymous to `-path` but it's not POSIX compliant.